# create dynamic card content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have multiple div classes as below. 
What I'm trying to do is that, when it is clicked 
my function should have created card contents(card-title, input-group-text) inside the card-body. but my current function(createCard()) creates some text content outside of the card-body. need your kind help

```
 <!-- My ejs file -->

 <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div style="height: 255px;padding-top:86px;color:#e2e2e2;">
              <i class="icon-plus icons font-2xl" style="font-size: 5rem !important;margin-left: 46%;cursor:pointer;" onclick="createCard()"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- my js file -->
function createCard() {
    var x = document.createElement("FORM");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myForm");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("value", "Donald");
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(y);
}
```

Comment: if i understood correctly you want to select the card-body and append the elements you created to that, now you're appending them to body element

Comment: You are appending it to document.body instead append it to your respective card (`card-body`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("value", "Donald");
document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")[0].appendChild(y);
```

you can do something like this assuming you have only one child and it will be present definitely

other wise there are various option available via jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You Need to appending the `input` and other required content to `card-body`.This you can do by getting `document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")[0]` and append the child in it.

**Here is a working snippet:**

```js
function createCard() {
    var x = document.createElement("FORM");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myForm");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("value", "Donald");
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")[0].appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">&nbsp;vcvcv</div>
          <div class="card-body">card-body</br></div>
            <div style="height: 255px;padding-top:86px;color:#e2e2e2;">
              <i class="icon-plus icons font-2xl" style="font-size: 5rem !important;margin-left: 46%;cursor:pointer;" onclick="createCard()">createCard</i>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```